# How to set server side of Meteor Mobile App to run on the device the app will be installed in

Tags: javascript, android, meteor

I have a meteor mobile app I have created.

When I run the app on a device via:

> meteor run android-device

The app runs ok as long as I keep the server running on my laptop.  However when I cancel the server running on my laptop it does not work properly anymore.

I have now finished programming the entire mobile app.
In order to create the APK I need to run the following command:

```
Meteor build <path> --server <host>:<port>
```

I would like to make sure that the server will run on the device that the app is installed so that the app will not be dependent on the internet for it to work properly when it calls a server side command via `Meteor.call`
Is this possible and how do I achieve this?

What values should I input to `<host>:<port>` in order to make sure that the server will run on the device where the Meteor app will be installed??

Comment: Are you expecting that the server process will run on the Android device? Meteor doesn't do that, it expects to run on a regular server of some kind

Comment: Yes I do...I was expecting that Meteor will package/combine both the Meteor server code I've written with the Meteor client code I've written into one standalone app that I can upload to the Appstores so that the users that download this app can use the app even when offline.  Anyway to achieve this?

Comment: It is possible to operate while offline, but your meteor methods won't be available - you have to work out some way of storing information locally on the device, which meteor doesn't do out of the box